# Android - como transportar informações da imageView de uma classe para outra?

Tags: java, android, mobile, imagem, intent

Olá, estou precisando transportar o conteúdo de uma ImageView de uma classe para outra, tentei por Intent, mas não consegui por ela. Possuo um Drawable que foi editada na ImageView da primeira classe e quero transportar esse conteúdo já editado para outra ImageView de outra classe.

Tentei desta forma como mostra abaixo, mas não deu certo..

Na primeira classe:

```
public void next(View v){
    //resultView é uma ImageView
    Bitmap p = drawableToBitmap(resultView.getDrawable());

    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putParcelable("BITMAP", p);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditImage.class);
    intent.putExtras(param);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Na segunda classe:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle param = intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap  bit = param.getParcelable("BITMAP");
        resultView.setImageBitmap(bit);
...
}
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda e atenção, caso alguém tenha alguma ideia ou dica de como se faz por favor informe, toda ajuda é valida. Abraço!

Comment: Estas imagens que você quer transportar, estão dentro do seu aplicativo?

Comment: Não, elas podem ser uma foto que a pessoa recém tirou, ou uma da galeria mas contendo edições. Tentei converter pra Bitmap e enviar, como mostra o exemplo da pergunta, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "não deu certo"? Dá algum erro?

Comment: Sim, o app para de funcionar com o erro (Unfortunately, NomeApp has stopped) 

O Android Studio informa que o erro ocorre nesta linha de código (            resultView.setImageBitmap(bit); )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, segui tentando aqui e consegui desta forma :)

Na Classe 1:

```
public void next(View v){
    Bitmap p = drawableToBitmap(resultView.getDrawable());

    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putParcelable("BITMAP", p);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Classe2.class);
    intent.putExtras(param);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Na Classe 2:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle param = intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap  bit = param.getParcelable("BITMAP");
        Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(bit);
        resultView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        ...
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda e atenção! :)